# MiKTeX service unavailable for downloading new packages

Tags: miktex

Here what I got :

> The MiKTeX web service has rejected your request.  Possible reason:
>   too many requests arriving from your IP address.

Any ideas ? I thought it could come from the location of the server (how to change it by the way ?)

With best regards.

Klauss

Comment: See the alert on http://www.miktex.org/

Comment: I hope it will be fix soon as possible. Thank you Ulrike.

Comment: It is only because of a packaging error in the newest babel package.

Comment: I just updated babel from the ftp.fernuni-hagen.de server and this worked fine. So the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: How to change server location ?

Comment: The update manager asks you. The package manager has an entry in the repositories menu.

Comment: I got this error before the update manager could ask me.

Comment: Then change the repository in the package manager, the update manager should pick it up. Or wait a bit.

Comment: Well, thank you for helping. Nevertheless I don't have so much time, I will probably install Tex-Live instead of Miktex. Best regards. Klauss.

Comment: MiKTeX authors could add the "Possible reason: repositories are temporarily offline due to configuration error." It's happened more than once in the past year, and this question has over 200 views already in one day.

Comment: The alert is gone, let's try it !